# Move item from org archive back into org agenda file?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** how does one move a project out of the `org` archive and back into its original spot in the agenda file?

`org-mode` has facilities to [archive projects](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Archiving).  Every once in a while, however, I need to retrieve something from the archive and put it back in the agenda file in which it was originally located.

I do this infrequently enough that it's not a big problem to move the entry from archive to agenda file manually, but I'm wondering if there's an automated way to do so.

Comment: Is there an indication in a drawer or elsewhere as to where the archived task originated from -- e.g., heading / file / etc.?  If so, then refiling it programmatically should be fairly easy if we have a sample format of what the archived tasks looks like -- so we can extract the original location and then programmatically hit the refile command.  I use `org-archive-subtree` all the time as a means of programmatically moving subtrees around the same file, or to different files -- setting via `let` the variables `org-archive-location` and `org-archive-save-context-info`.